# How can I customize TableComparatorChooser to responds to single mouse clicks?

Tags: java, clickonce, glazedlists

I have a GlazedList table, when i want to sort a column i should double click.
I want to change it to a single click.

**Does anyone know how to do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `TableComparatorChooser.MULTIPLE_COLUMN_MOUSE` to `TableComparatorChooser.SINGLE_COLUMN`